# How can I know which objects can I call with $ in a function?

Tags: r, summary

For example with function `summary()` I have the next outcome:

```
> summary(mod.exp.simp)

Forecast method: Simple exponential smoothing

Model Information:
Simple exponential smoothing 

Call:
 ses(y = serie19) 

  Smoothing parameters:
    alpha = 1e-04 

  Initial states:
    l = 113.5986 

  sigma:  23.9139

     AIC     AICc      BIC 
139.7080 141.8898 141.8321 

Error measures:
                      ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 7.32631e-05 22.26259 16.13435 -3.387759 13.98894 0.6306587 0.2215178

Forecasts:
         Point Forecast   Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2021.667       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2022.000       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2022.333       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2022.667       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2023.000       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2023.333       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2023.667       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2024.000       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2024.333       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
2024.667       113.5986 82.9518 144.2455 66.72834 160.4689
```

I would like to use something like this:

```
summary(mod.exp.simp)$error_measures

                  ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE      ACF1
Training set 7.32631e-05 22.26259 16.13435 -3.387759 13.98894 0.6306587 0.2215178
```

but I don't know which is the name for call those outcomes and if exist some function to know that information.

Comment: Look at `type` or `attributes`?!

Comment: I usually use `str` if I do not find it in the `help` page under "value".

Comment: To find the help page you will need to know what function produced object `mod.exp.simp` which you did not tell us. Try `?summary.functionname` to get a manual page for the version of summary that works with those object if the summary function information is not included on `?functionname`.

Comment: @dcarlson I used mod.exp.simp= ses(serie) where serie is a time serie

Comment: Try `names(summary(mod.exp.simp))`

Comment: Apparently `summary(mod.exp.simp)` just returns the `mod.exp.simp` object which does not contain the error measures.

Comment: Try adding the result of `dput(summary(mod.exp.simp))` to your question or read @MrFlick s comment more closely...